# Python 2.7.3 . . . Write .jpg/.png image file?

Tags: python, image, file, text, fwrite

So I have a .jpg/.png and I opened it up in Text Edit which I provided below:

**Is there anyway I can save these exotic symbols to a string in Python to later write that to a file to produce an image?**

I tried to import a string that had the beta symbol in it and I got an error that send Non-ASCII so I am assuming the same would happen for this.

Is there anyway to get around this problem?

Thanks

Portion of Image.png in Text Edit:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you just want to copy the image into a different file -- because if it is, then you don't really need to read the whole thing into memory all at once.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no attempt to solve whatsoever by OP - no code.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What you are looking at in your text edit is a binary file, trying to represent it all in human readable characters.

Just open the file as binary in python:

```
with open('picture.png', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

with open('picture_out.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: This kind of thing is easier in Python 3, which will shout at you the second you mix up binary data with text. One of the many reasons Python 3 rules.

Comment: @delnan: And when Python 3 is supported by every package and library out there..it will **actually** rule :-) One of the important reasons it currently doesn't rule

Answer (score 0):

You can read to file in binary format by providing the `rb` flag to `open` and then just save what ever comes out of the file into a text file. I don't know what the point of this would be but there you go

```
# read in image data
fh = open('test.png','rb')
data = fh.read()
fh.close()

# write gobbledigoock to text file
fh = open('test.txt','w')
fh.write(data)
fh.close
fh.close()
```